# How does one apportion returns to multiple investors when their times and amounts of investment were different?

Tags: accounting

No accounting experience here.

The problem: 
Man A invests $10 on day 1.
Man B invests $5 on day 4.
Man C invests $85 on day 5.

On day 7, the $100 returns 10%. How do you fairly distribute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like an **investment club**.  Assuming the securities being purchased can be easily valued at each point of purchase (e.g. if they are public securities being purchased), then you can use a *unit valuation system*.  See [Wikipedia - Unit Valuation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_Valuation_System): *"UVS is a time weighted performance metric"*.

Then calculating the rates of return for A, B, and C would be based on their respective unit holdings and purchases.  You could use IRR on each set.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the arrangements made at the time of each investment.  Who set it up and what provisions did they make?  In a short timeframe like your example, the arrangements may be simple, like 1 share of ownership for each $5.  Then, on day 7 there are 20 shares, so that man A gets 2/20ths of the distribution, B 1/20th, and C 17/20ths.

If the timeframe were years, then different arrangements would probably be made because the value gained by the $10 over the first 3 years might be significant.  The obvious way to account for this is that the cost of a share would be different for B than A.  If A got 2 shares by putting in $10, but the worth of the investment in year 4 is $20, then B maybe would get only 0.5 shares.  Later, say C gets 6.5 shares for his $85.  Then there are a total of 9 shares, and distributions would be 2/9ths for A, 0.5/9th for B, and 6.5/9ths for C.